# MMMMMMSS what kind of a time duration format is this?

Tags: c#, format

i have a file which states duration for a particular event in format MMMMMMSS.Does any one know what kind of format is this for time duration and how to convert it into seconds.I'm using C# language

Comment: Can you give example of input and desired output?

Comment: 6 `M` in a row is not a [standard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) or [custom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) format string.

Comment: Any string of `M` longer than 4 is interpreted as `MMMM` which returns the long name of the month (e.g. "August"). The issue is with `SS` which doesn't correspond with anything; `ss`, on the other hand, is the left-zero-padded seconds. Perhaps that wasn't supposed to be a .NET format string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the format is really `M...MSS` (supplied as an integer `value`), converting it to seconds is quite easy:

```
var seconds = (value / 100) * 60 + (value % 100);
```

Why does it work?

- `value / 100` removes the last two digits ([integer division](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b1ff23f.aspx)), thus returning `MMMMMM`, and
- `value % 100` returns the last two digits ([modulo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx)), i.e., `SS`.
- The remainder of the formula is `MMMMMM * 60 + SS`, which should be pretty self-explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

My guess based on the format is that it could hold a maximum value of `99999959`, which would mean `999999` minutes and `59` seconds. But that is pure conjecture, and some sample data would help to bolster this idea. You may never know for certain though.

You should at least be able to determine whether the SS part ever exceeds 59 or not, which would be very important to know.

```
var input = "02345612";
int minutes = int.Parse(input.Substring(0, 6));
int seconds = int.Parse(input.Substring(6, 2));
int totalSeconds = minutes * 60 + seconds;
```